# Realtek RTL8188CE don't appear while installing Linux Mint

Tags: wifi

When I logged in to the installer, I found that my wireless wasn't working. This is strange because in every other Linux Mint installation I've done, wireless cards are recognized automatically, I continued the installation until the end using ethernet, when I logged in, I couldn't turn on Wi-Fi. So I went to the magical google.ca and found the command `inxi -n` which returned this:

```
 Network:  
 Card-1: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller driver: r8169 
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: e8:40:f2:f0:65:57

Card-2: Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter driver: rtl8192ce 
           IF: wlan0 state: down mac: 74:e5:43:3b:c2:38
```

The important bit being the second part, where it says state: down I looked around a bit more and found a script, which when ran, this caught my eye:

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: `Hard blocked: yes` might indicate a hardware switch disabled the WiFi. This is particularly common on Dell machines. Are you sure you didn't accidentally flip a switch?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: lsmod | grep wmi Thanks.

Comment: I just sent my computer in for repairs, I'll reply when I can :)